# How to filter a query to show only results where a column can't be converted to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table with a varchar column with values that should be integers (legacy application, built way before I got to the company).

I need to get a list of all the records that cannot be converted to integers, in order to fix them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is:

```
select MyColumn
from MyTable
where isnumeric(MyColumn) = 0
```

That assumes you are OK with losing decimals when you convert.

Answer (score 3):

If fractions or non-standard representations (like `1.3` or `1E8`) can be considered "convertible to int" for your purposes, then use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   IsNumeric(myfield) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

ISNUMERIC does just not cut it for empty strings (= zero) or decimals.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

This negative searches for anything that has characters outside the 0-9 range. Do you gave negative ints?

Comment: `SQL Server` does not support regular expressions even in `2008R2`, to say nothing of `2000`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: it's a simple LIKE query, no?

Comment: it definitely is, but it will only match strings having literal `[^0-9]` in them. The regexp won't be expanded (which I believe was your goal)

Comment: @Quassnoi: ^ means NOT. So it would give anything that is not all numbers

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a regular expression.  Not sure which DBMS you are using but something like this might work for your DB.  It should find records with characters (upper/lower) case in some_column.

SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE some_column SIMILAR TO ‘%[A-Z | a-z]%’;

Comment: "Not sure which DBMS you are using" is great!